# HTML5 Canvas: Maximum value blending

Tags: javascript, canvas

The HTML5 canvas element support several blend modes.  In order to create an intensity height map that combines the intensities of several overlapping sources, I'd like to draw the individual intensity source maps (canvas) to a large common canvas using `ctx.drawImage`.

Therefore, I'm looking for a blend mode that retains (in gray scale) the **maximum** value of the two sources.  More specifically, using RGB colors (R, G, B),

- blending (10,10,10) and (123,123,123) should yield (123,123,123).

Can this be achieved with one (or possibly a combination) of the HTML5 canvas blend modes?  I'm also open for other techniques (like abusing the alpha value or using the hue etc, if it helps).

I've looked at the various blend modes available, but the closest modes (darken/lighten/multiply) don't seem to be a good match.

I'm currently using individual pixel manipulation, but the performance is not good enough.

Update: I'm looking for something similar to OpenGL's `GL_EXT_blend_minmax`

Comment: What about (12, 100, 100) and (200, 15, 15) ? Do you want to keep the pixels with max sum of rgb values or luminosity or something else ? In HTML5, canvas element as `lighten` and `luminosity` blend modes. Here is a pen with all the modes : http://codepen.io/adobe/pen/nmfic

Comment: Since I'm currently using gray scale colors only, the individual color components are equal.  A true "maximum" blend would probably yield (200,100,100). As stated in my question, "lighten" does not seem to achieve the desired effect, neither seems "luminosity".